# why my page is not showing background color when i have added the css

Tags: html, css

HTML code:-

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>The block-chain website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the css code:-

```css
    *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .container{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #42455a;
    }
```

the problem in my page is that the div with that color is not coming on screen.

Comment: Try to add  ```body{min-height:100vh}``` above your ```.container``` class

Comment: you have to add `body,html{ width: 100%;
    height: 100%;}`(the reason is because you have to declare the parents `height/width` if you use `%`) see here:https://jsfiddle.net/8rnwq5Lg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` and `height` properties of `html` and `body` are not set.
They will automatically be set by content within them.
Since you just have a div without content, defining `width` and `height` properties will not make `body` and `html` expand as you define those percentages dependant on the parent dimensions.

Just define `width` and `height` of `html` and `body`:

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #42455a;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly,could you please explain the process.

Comment: width of the body will be 100vw, not 0

Answer (score 0):

So you tell your `.container` to have `height: 100%;` - but actually your `div.container` is the only element currently *creating* any `height` within the `body`.

This creates the following render situation:

1. `div.container` requests to be rendered at `height: 100%`.
2. To calculate how many pixels that actually translates to, the browser checks the parent element, which is the `body`, because `100%` means `100% of parent element height`.
3. So to calculate the height of the `body`, the browser needs to check the *children* of the `body`, since the default `height` for `body` is `auto` and because those are the elements that actually ***create*** height.

That is the reason for your `div.container` not being visible - it has 100% of `0px` height - which happens to be `0px` as well.

To fix it, simply apply `height: 100vh;` (100% of **v**iewport **h**eight) to the `body` element:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #42455a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```